# How do I include google fonts?

Tags: fonts

What is the easiest way of using google fonts in a LaTeX document if I want to maintain full microtype support (i.e. without using xelatex)?

Thanks!

Comment: Does a very long job with `otf2tfm`, carefully checking the produced metric font files and doing a complex installation (several hours' work) qualify for “an easy way”?

Comment: Assuming the fonts in question are in opentype or truetype format, you're probably best off becoming familiar with LuaLaTeX. Its support for the `microtype` package is nearly as complete as that of pdfLaTeX, but certainly better than than of XeLaTeX.

Comment: Thanks Mico.  No, egreg, it does not.

Comment: Note that it’s worth, um, googling for the source of the fonts, because Google modifies them for the needs of the web, which are not those of `luatex` or `xetex`.  E.g., the Sorts Mill Goudy at http://www.google.com/fonts lacks the small caps found in the `.otf` version at https://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/.  Many opentype features may be removed when fonts are optimized for the web.

Comment: @egreg To be fair, the question didn't ask for 'an easy way' but only 'the easiest' which might be extremely difficult despite being easier than all the others. (Indeed, if *full* `microtype` support is required, it will be. However, I'm not sure there is much point in this with web-optimised fonts, as has been pointed out...)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the web-based nature of these fonts.  The answers will help me with the use of fonts more generally.

Comment: @JPi are you still looking for solutions here or did the comments lead you to your own answer?

Comment: I had not realized Therese's point, so I didn't pursue this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a localized request which the OP is no longer pursuing.